# Can you change css variables in anime js?

Tags: javascript, css-variables, anime.js

I wanted to know if/how you can change css variables in anime js.  Please tell me this.  Thank you!

Comment: There is an open issue on their GitHub for this feature. It's not possible yet, but may be in the future. https://github.com/juliangarnier/anime/issues/449

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I found this set up to be the easiest, pre-4.0.0:

```
const header = headerRef.current

const cssVariables = {
  twBgOpacity: '100%',
}

anime({
  targets: cssVariables,
  twBgOpacity: ['100%', '0%'],
  easing: 'easeOutQuad',
  duration: 200,
  update: () => {
    header.style.setProperty('--tw-bg-opacity', cssVariables.twBgOpacity)
  },
})
```

I'm using React in this example. Without React, the `header` variable should be `const header = document.querySelector('header')`.

### A few notes on how this works:

The `update` function can be used for just about anything, and will fire for every iteration (`100%` to `0%` in this case). The important thing is, we don't want to target the element directly. Rather, we want to target a variable of an object (I labeled it cssVariables, since that's what we're changing) with the start value.

Since our target is an object, we can change the value of one of its properties (`twBgOpacity`). Just like normal, we use an array of values in the `anime` object to iterate between the values.

Now we can use the `update` function to make changes to our element—or anything else—using the value(s) of our `cssVariables` object. To change the CSS variable(s) on the selected element, we just use the usual JavaScript `el.style.setProperty` method to set the CSS variable on the element's `style` attribute.

I hope this helps.

Comment: "...I found this set up to be the easiest, pre-4.0.0..." is anime.js version 4.0.0 available?

Comment: @user3163495 No, but they officially announced the feature will be added when 4.0.0 is released.